# Can I turn an Element ID into a variable using JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want to store the ID in a variable, I want to use it as a variable to access an object.

Ex:

```
function Location(name, state)

var city = new Location("Baltimore", "Maryland");

<a href="#" id="city" onclick="function(this)">
```

The purpose is so that when the function runs it can use the element ID to print out "Baltimore" for example.

Currently anything I've tried returns undefined

Comment: Can you please provide some more details.?

Comment: If you're using `onclick="function(this)` the argument supplied to the function is the clicked object. What more do you want?

Comment: edited to maybe/hopefully clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ID as a key, makes it easier when you don't have to mess with parent scope etc.

```
 <a href="#" id="city" onclick="fn(this)">city</a>
 <a href="#" id="country" onclick="fn(this)">country</a>
```

and then

```
var obj = {
     city    : {name : 'New York'},
     country : {name : 'USA'}
}

function fn(elem) {
    var value = obj[elem.id].name;
}
```

Comment: I was in the middle of typing this.. +1. But to truly answer the OP's question, you might want to make it a hash of objects.

Comment: Do my edits change this answer at all? I'm still getting undefined

Comment: @BrantBarton - I really have no idea what you're trying to do, but `new Object("Baltimore", "Maryland");` would probably just give you an object with all the letters as keys, so it's not at all what you think it is.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update some of the code when I edited. It's been a looooong day.

Answer (score 0):

though you can do that, you should use `data` attribute instead.

```
// assuming that `city` is global variable.
var city = new Object();

function(eventTarget) {
   var id = eventTarget.getAttribute('data-id');// or `eventTarget.id` to get id, if you prefer not to use `data` attribute.
   console.log(window[id]);
}


<a href="#" data-id="city" onClick="foo(this)">
```